# Actionscript 2 - setProperty

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

```
setProperty("tvmenuitem"+i, _x, "300");
```

works fine.

However how can I set times.text = "1234";

I tried:
    setProperty("tvmenuitem"+i, times.text, "1234");
But I get a syntax error.

```
Property name expected in GetProperty.
```

My Other problem is

```
setProperty("tvmenuitem"+i, _y, 100*i);
```

doesn't seem to work, the movie clip isn't moved. :(
If it has to be string how to I typecast it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the setProperty function, it is deprecated.

Assuming the numbered tvmenuitems are in the current scope and that times is a TextFiled that is a child of the tvmenuitem, you can use this kind of syntax:

```
this["tvmenuitem"+i]._x = 300;
this["tvmenuitem"+i]._y = 100*i;
this["tvmenuitem"+i].times.text = "1234";
```

Comment: hm.. setProperty("tvmenuitem"+i, _y, "100"); works but this["tvmenuitem"+i]._y = "100"; doesn't :(

Comment: It will work in ActionScript 2. The _y problem is probably because of something else (using a string, "100", is probably not it but you should use a number, not a string).

Comment: links = XPathAPI.selectNodeList(this.firstChild, "/syba/linkgroup[@name='tvshows']/link[@type='tvshow']");
for(i=0;i<links.length;i++)
{
 duplicateMovieClip("tvmenuitem", "tvmenuitem"+i, 1);
 _root["tvmenuitem"+i]._y = 100 + 100*i;
}

Comment: I had to duplicateMovieClip("tvmenuitem", "tvmenuitem"+i, i);